# Interfacing with Sqlalchemy query object to extend, custom query types

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm working on adding pagination functionality to my models. I could do this with a method in a mixin, I think I understand what pagination is in this context, but I'm looking to add queries so I can pass in pagination wherever I want without hard coding a model method and without a mixin e.g.:

```
Mymodel.query.filter(Mymodel.attr=='X').paginate(**args, **kwargs)
```

flask-sqlalchemy does this, but I'm not using that, though I've gone over it to attempt to extract some of the functionality.

So if I have something like this method:

```
def paginate(self, page, per_page=20):
        items = self.limit(per_page).offset((page - 1) * per_page).all()
        return Pagination(self, page, per_page, self.count(), items)
```

How do I insert that as something with an interface in and out in the sqlalchemy query chain? I somewhat do and don't follow how it is being done in flask-sqlalchemy, but I want to extract/learn how to do this and more control over querying in the future, refine my use of sqlalchemy, so I do not exactly know where I'm going with it, just asking a question and going from there.

Long answer: to keep reading the sqlalchemy docs and code until I achieve greater understanding. I'm looking to extend orm.Query -- which I've done, but I don't see how I can tie this into my project yet because I don't understand the underlying mechanics of sqlalchemy, but I think I just need to add my paginate query to the declarative base Base I'm using but will see once I get back to working on it.

Answer (score -2):

Have you read this yet ?

http://packages.python.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/api.html?highlight=pagination#flask.ext.sqlalchemy.Pagination

It clearly explains that to use pagination with sqlalchemy extension within flask, you do this:

```
class flask.ext.sqlalchemy.Pagination(query, page, per_page, total, items)¶
```

In your specific case, you can do:

```
myquery = Mymodel.query.filter(Mymodel.attr=='X')
pagination = Pagination(myquery,page,per_page,total,items)
```

Then in your template, you can use this pagination object to render using render_pagination() macro

Comment: This I understand and have no problem with, so perhaps I should clarify. I want to be able to manipulate the Query object to make using a 'pagination' viable at approximately any point in the chain. Basequery.paginate returns this and I already have the idea of the Paginate class down. In other words, I want to avoid hardcoding the small p pagination query for each and every model, instead build a way to extend orm.Query *like* I'm seeing flask-sqla do. I'm looking to do Basequery.paginate on my own as part of what I'm doing, without needing to go through the hoops of Flask-Sqlalchemy.